# Delete An ArrayList from SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I know there are couple examples of this but i tried many of them and i couldn't fix my issue.I want to delete an ArrayList from my shared preferences.

I create my ArrayList on shared preference in the **first** activity:

```
 public void saveArrayList(ArrayList<String> list){
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(list);
    editor.putString("testShared", json);
    editor.apply();     // This line is IMPORTANT !!!
}
```

On my **second** activity i retrieve my array like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_food_basket);

    alreadyAddedFoodtest = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.alreadyAddedList);
    registerForContextMenu(alreadyAddedFoodtest);

    getArrayList();


}
 public ArrayList<String> getArrayList(){
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(AddFoodBasket.this);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = prefs.getString("testShared", null);
    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>() {}.getType();
    itemsAdded=gson.fromJson(json, type);
    return itemsAdded;
}
```

And finally i delete the arrays items in my **second** activity here:

```
 public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    if(item.getItemId()==R.id.delete){

        AddFood add=new AddFood();

        count--;
        countTextbasket(count);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Διαγράφηκε"+item,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo(); // init the info the position from
        itemsAdded.remove(info.position); // remove the item from the list
        addedAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();//updating the adapter

        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("testShared", MODE_PRIVATE);
        preferences.edit().clear().apply();

    }else{
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The problem is that

`SharedPreferences preferencesgetSharedPreferences("testShared", MODE_PRIVATE);
preferences.edit().clear().apply();`

Doesn't work so when i open my activity again the list is there again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getSharedPreferences()` doesn't do what you think it does. The String you pass to it is the name of that set of SharedPreferences and anything stored in that instance will be in its own file.

For instance, using

```
getSharedPreferences("hello", ...).edit().putString("test", "something").apply();
```

will create a whole new file in your app's data directory (`preferences_hello.xml`), where the `test/something` key/value is stored.

`getSharedPreferences()` doesn't get a specific preference, it gets a specific set of preferences. `getDefaultSharedPreferences()` actually calls `getSharedPreferences()` internally and passes your app's package name.

You are currently saving `testShared` to the default SharedPreferences (`getDefaultSharedPreferences()`). If you want to clear that value, use

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit().remove("testShared").apply();
```

Comment: I think it works but when i go back to my first activity and open the second activity again i got this error      `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference`.

Comment: Never mind your answer is correct i will fix the other problem!Thanks

Comment: @AlexKolydas likely because you're calling `getArrayList()`, which is now null.

Answer (score 1):

When you clear the prefs you do this:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("testShared", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

This means you want a specific preference set with that name. Your other preferences aren’t named so they will be a different set.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(AddFoodBasket.this);
```

Use the exact same way to get the preferences and then set the key you want to null, or if you want to delete all preferences you can `clear()` them.